# ServiceStack REST service custom path error

Tags: iis-7.5, servicestack

I am having trouble configuring my ServiceStack REST service to work on my production IIS 7.5 box.  It works fine running localhost, and it also works fine if I deploy in the root of "Default Web Site" -  /EmployeeSvc.  I have a virtual directory structure under Default Web Site for organizational purposes (note custom path in web.config).  I can browse successfully to the default.htm at this location, but when I try to execute the built-in /hello example I receive:

Server Error 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Like I said, the built-in /hello example works perfectly from localhost and from a root iis folder under default web site, but not from within a directory structure.  What am I doing wrong with the location-path?

Thanks in advance!  Here is web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="Employees-NoAuth/WebServices/EmployeeSvc">
        <system.web>
          <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
          </httpHandlers>
        </system.web>

        <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
        <system.webServer>
          <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
          <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
          <handlers>
            <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" verb="*" />
          </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Note: "Server Error 404 - File or directory not found" is an ASP.NET error, i.e. your path isn't making it to the ServiceStack handler - that's the first thing that needs resolving.

Comment: I am very new to servicestack, but do you by any chance have additional system.webServer entry in your web.config? I had the same problem using service stack along the ria services. If you do let me know, and I'll tell you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following:
 1. Remove location node from web.config. Move SS configuration out of it.
 2. Register base URL path in your class derived from `AppHostBase`:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "base/path" });
}
```